# T SQL- Use Results of One Query as a variable for Other Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written this query; I need help in assigning variable; which is coming from other query, How can I do that.

How can I combine them together?

Query 1

```
Select SUM(Credit)
FROM(SELECT TOP 1  Credit
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 Ref, Credit, PaymentID 
FROM  Payment where  Ref =  '????'  AND PaymentID <= '????' 
ORDER BY PaymentID DESC)
a ORDER BY PaymentID)
b
```

Query 2

```
Select Ref, PaymentID 
From Payment
Where PaymentDate = '2012-09-23'
```

SO I need Ref and PaymentID of Query 2 and use as variable in Query 1

Comment: What do you mean by combine them? What would be the end result? Use the result _where_ in the second query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a join

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 Ref, Credit, PaymentID      
FROM  Payment 
    inner join
    (Select Ref, PaymentID  From Payment Where PaymentDate = '2012-09-23' ) query2
        on Payment.Ref = query2.Ref and Payment.PaymentID <= query2.PaymentID      
ORDER BY PaymentID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @yourvar

Select @yourvar = SUM(Credit)....

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the fields you need as variables:

```
DECLARE @REF        varchar(20)
DECLARE @PaymentID  int

SET @REF =  (Select Ref
                From Payment
                Where PaymentDate = '2012-09-23')

SET @PaymentID =    (Select PaymentID
                    From Payment
                    Where PaymentDate = '2012-09-23')

Select  SUM(Credit)
FROM(SELECT TOP 1  Credit
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 Ref, Credit, PaymentID 
FROM  Payment where  Ref IN(@REF)  AND PaymentID <= @PaymentID
ORDER BY PaymentID DESC)
a ORDER BY PaymentID)
b
```

**EDIT: I'm guessing PaymentID is a INT and Ref is a varchar field. You can change in the declare statement in case it's other datatype.**